# FastAPI/Unvicorn request hanging during invocation of call_next (path operation function) in middleware

Tags: python, python-requests, fastapi, uvicorn

We have a machine learning model inside a docker container running on EC2.

We use Cortex.dev to autoscale GPUs.

Non-deterministically, requests will hang during the `call_next` function in the FastAPI middleware. Unfortunately, it's not reproducible.

The `Middleware pre-request` print line gets logged, but the first print statement in the path operation function never gets logged.

Things we tried:

- Running Uvicorn with 1 worker
- Running without async for the `run` function
- Running with with `bytes` as the parameter type for `image` instead of `UploadFile`

None of these changes solve the hanging issue, but this is the most performant configuration.

1. Does this mean the issue is with FastAPI and not Uvicorn?
2. If yes, what could cause FastAPI to hang? If no, where is the problem and what would fix it?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.4.0-runtime-ubuntu18.04

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get install -y --fix-missing \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    ffmpeg \
    libsm6 \
    libxext6 \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

ADD ./requirements.txt ./

# install our dependencies
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip && python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt && apt-get clean && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

ADD ./ ./

ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8

EXPOSE 8080

CMD uvicorn api:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --workers 2
```

**api.py**

```
from my_predictor import PythonPredictor
from typing import Optional
from datetime import datetime
import time
from starlette.responses import Response

from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, Form, Response, HTTPException, Request
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

origins = ["*"]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


@app.middleware("http")
async def add_process_time_header(request: Request, call_next):
    cortex_id = request.headers.get('x-request-id')
    start_time = time.time()
    print("Cortex ID: " + cortex_id + ". > Middleware pre-request. Time stamp: " + str(start_time), flush=True)

    response = await call_next(request)

    process_time = time.time() - start_time
    print("Cortex ID: " + cortex_id + ". > Middleware post-response. Duration: " + str(process_time), flush=True)

    return response



@app.post("/")
async def run(request: Request, image: UploadFile = File(...), renderFactor:Optional[int] = Form(12), requestId:Optional[str] = Form('-1'),include_header:Optional[str] = Form('bin')):

    try:
        cortexId = request.headers.get('x-request-id')
        print("Cortex ID: " + cortexId + ". Request ID: " + requestId + " >>> Request received. Time stamp: " + str(datetime.now()))

        start = time.time()
    
        image = await image.read()

        payload = {}
        payload['image'] = image
        payload['renderFactor'] = renderFactor
        payload['requestId'] = requestId
        payload['include_header'] = include_header
        
        response = pred.predict(payload)

        end = time.time()

        totalTime = round(end - start, 2)

        print("Cortex ID: " + cortexId + ". Request ID: " + requestId + " > Request processed. Duration: " + str(totalTime) + " seconds. Time stamp: " + str(datetime.now()))

        if totalTime > 5:
            print("Long request detected. Duration: " + str(totalTime))

        return response
        
    except Exception as error:
        end = time.time()
        print(str(error))
        print("Cortex ID: " + cortexId + ". Request ID: " + requestId + " > Error. Duration: " + str(round(end - start, 2)) + " seconds . Time stamp: " + str(datetime.now()))

        raise HTTPException(status_code = 500, detail = str(error))

config = {}
pred = PythonPredictor(config)
```

Comment: `docker exec -it ${image_id} bash` into running container and debug with gdb - https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb

Comment: @NikitaAlmakov thanks for the help. we were able to generate this trace, but am stuck isolating what exactly causes the container to hang: https://gist.github.com/panabee/1710b94f2a6d1291051b55f26bab54fc. any more advice?

Comment: try checking every thread: `info threads`, e.g. `thread 2` and then
`py-up`, `py-down` and `py-list` commands to review each level of the stack -  https://devguide.python.org/gdb/

Comment: Can you try http 202 as a workaround? https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/3

Comment: Also, check this ticket for non blocking asyncio and configuring uvicorn for long time requests

Comment: @NikitaAlmakov as you can see here in this gist, we checking the code for the most suspect thread (thread 7, cuda-EvtHandlr), but get `Unable to locate gdb frame for python bytecode interpreter`: https://gist.github.com/panabee/8af76076f69aa95a429eb7f9dd73caa1

Comment: @LiorPollak which ticket for configuring uvicorn for long-time requests and non-blocking asyncio? it seems the link was lost.

Comment: Only found this- https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#timeout but seems to me that a more reasonable way to solve it would be running it as a job in the background in order not to hang the worker

Comment: @LiorPollak we're not using gunicorn. only uvicorn + fastapi inside a kubernetes cluster. we use the cluster to scale up containers instead of adding multiple processes to a single container. happen to have any other ideas?

Comment: The most suitable idea I have is to add the job to be executed in the background so it won’t block the workers…  when I say execute in the background I mean it can also be sent to another micro service that will execute it, and maybe expose the job status via the api

Answer (score 9):

#### The Basic Info, Root-Cause & the Rant

Hey, I have spent a fair amount of time stuck in this hanging issue (for critical apps in my org which have multiple custom MDW). This is basically because `@app.middleware("http")` based middlewares, are in back-end created by inheriting from  Starlette's `BaseHTTPMiddleware`. So this problem also exists for MDWs written by inheriting from `BaseHTTPMiddleware` explicitly. The reasons for this are quite complex and this is what I have understood so far:

1. from [here (GitHub Starlette Issue)](https://github.com/encode/starlette/issues/919) and [here (Github FastAPI Issue)](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/394): I learnt that this method uses `StreamingResponse` which has some issues
2. from [here (GitHub Starlette Issue)](https://github.com/encode/starlette/issues/847): I learnt that one of the reasons for hanging is: awaiting `request.json()` is allowed only once in request life-cycle in API, and `BaseHTTPMiddleware` also creates a Request object on its own (which causes hanging issue, since that is another request)

The last link also mentions that what also causes the hanging issue, is that, because of `StreamingResponse`; the *reading of response* somehow gets exhausted in the first read, and when it comes to the second read, it keeps on waiting for it indefinitely which causes the hanging. (first and second read here means: in ASGI APPs, messages are sent to-and-from client & APP with various types like `http.response.start`, `http.response.body` etc)

#### The Solution

So, don't use anything to do with `BaseHTTPMiddleware`. To combat this I wrote all my custom middlewares using ASGI Specification given [here](https://asgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specs/main.html)

You can make your custom middleware like this:

```py
from starlette.types import ASGIApp, Receive, Send, Message

class LogProcessingTime:

    def __init__(self, app: ASGIApp) -> None:
        self.app = app
    
    async def __call__(self, scope: Scope, receive: Receive, send: Send):
        
        start_time = time.time()

        async def send_wrapper(message: Message):
            # This will capture response coming from APP Layer
            # response body will be in message where the type is
            # "http.response.body"
            if message["type"] == "http.response.body":
                process_time = time.time() - start_time
                # you can log this process_time now any way you prefer

            await send(message)
        
        await self.app(scope, receive, send_wrapper)


# you can add this to your app this way:
app.add_middleware(LogProcessingTime)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the only problem was `starlette`'s version. I upgraded from `0.21.0` to `0.28.0` and the problem was solved.
I used the command below:

`pip install --upgrade starlette`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

From your code I can see you have used Response from both `starlette.responses` package and `FastAPI`'s Response package which might have caused the hanging issue

```
from starlette.responses import Response

# remove the Response from fastapi
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, Form, HTTPException, Request
```

**Solution 2**

If your issue still persists

[FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/) states the `Request` that imported from `fastapi` package is ideally from `Starlette`([Starlette Requests documentation link](https://www.starlette.io/requests/))

> You could also use `from starlette.requests import Request`.
> **FastAPI** provides it as a convenience for you, the developer. But it comes directly from **Starlette**.

Replace `from fastapi import Request` with **`from starlette.requests import Request`**

There was a similar issue in official FastAPI github issues in [this link](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/394), the application was run with **`uvicorn <file>:app`**.
The below codeblock implemented directly with `starlette.requests` did not produce issue of hanging, suggesting the issue was due to FastAPI.

```
from starlette.applications import Starlette
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.responses import JSONResponse

app = Starlette()


@app.middleware("http")
async def func(request: Request, call_next):
    #print(await request.json())
    return await call_next(request)


@app.route('/', methods=["POST"])
def homepage(request):
    return JSONResponse({"Hello": "World"})
```

Ensure to use **`starlette.requests`** and **`starlette.responses`** in your code as below

```
from starlette.responses import Response
from starlette.requests import Request

# Request and Response removed from fastapi as directly referred from starlette
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, Form, HTTPException 
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

origins = ["*"]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


@app.middleware("http")
async def add_process_time_header(request: Request, call_next):
    cortex_id = request.headers.get('x-request-id')
    start_time = time.time()
    print("Cortex ID: " + cortex_id + ". > Middleware pre-request. Time stamp: " + str(start_time), flush=True)

    response = await call_next(request)

    process_time = time.time() - start_time
    print("Cortex ID: " + cortex_id + ". > Middleware post-response. Duration: " + str(process_time), flush=True)

    return response
```

Comment: @crashalot do implement directly with `starlette.requests` instead of `fastapi`'s `Request`. This will solve your hanging issue

Comment: Looking at this issue (https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/394), it's not clear where the problem is isolated to the FastAPI Response object. Do you mind sharing what you meant exactly, or where we could learn more? Thanks!

Comment: @Crashalot solution 1 refers to correction in your code as you have referenced `Response` object twice once from `starlette.responses` and other from `fastapi`. As shown in your code here `from starlette.responses import Response` and other response object referenced `from fastapi import FastAPI,File,UploadFile,Form,Response,……`

Comment: If solution 1 doesn’t fix your issue. Instead of referring to **Request** object from fastapi refer from `starlette.request` the GitHub issue raised by the person quotes they face hanging issues when using `from fastapi import Request` but didn’t face any issue with relevant code implementation in starlette.request.

Comment: unfortunately this didn't fix the issue. it's still hanging in the middleware for some reason, and sometimes doesn't even hit the print statement in our `run` function.

Comment: We posted a separate, but potentially related, problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70162157/fastapi-or-starlette-substantial-latency-added-after-call-next-function-in-midd. Would love your advice if you have time.

Comment: As you can see by the related question, the problem actually seems to occur before `call_next` -- not after. that is, the latency occurs between the middleware receiving a request and the path operation function receiving the request.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the "hanging issue" that consume request.body() multiple time is fixed by Starlette project in 2023.